# regex to get “words” containing only letters and neglect the combination of letters and numbers

Tags: regex

I want to write a RegExpression to select only letters and neglect the combination of both letters and numbers.

Eg:

```
1 1023 IO1234H ENGINE OIL SERVO 1230 4203 58% 20%
```

output :

```
ENGINE OIL SERVO
```

Comment: What regex have you tried, and what was the result of that attempt?

Comment: Agree with Joseph.  The things you have tried gives the reader a sense of what help you need as well as some additioknal insight about your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this

```
\b([a-zA-Z])*\b
```

[**Test it here**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%29*%5Cb&i=Eg%3A%201%201023%20IO1234H%20ENGINE%20OIL%20SERVO%201230%204203%2058%25%2020%25%20output%20%3A)

---

**Explanation**

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. The question was only asking about RegEx, not c#, and this answers it.